# Android app run on mobile data connection volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

How to run Android app on mobile data with volley or asynctask or Advance networking library? I have tried a lot of solution but my Android app not run on mobile data. I have increased volley timeout but not resolve my problem.

Below show my all code with volley library but my problem are not solved with this code also.

```
firstName = etFirstName.getText().toString();
        lastName = etLastName.getText().toString();
        email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(firstName)) {
            etFirstName.setError("Required");
            etFirstName.requestFocus();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lastName)) {
            etLastName.setError("Required");
            etLastName.requestFocus();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            etEmail.setError("Required");
            etEmail.requestFocus();
        } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            etEmail.setError("invalid email");
            etEmail.requestFocus();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            etPassword.setError("Required");
            etPassword.requestFocus();
        } else {
            etFirstName.setError(null);
            etLastName.setError(null);
            etEmail.setError(null);
            etPassword.setError(null);
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                try {
                    dialog.show();

                    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.url + "register.php",
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String result) {
                                    if (!dialog.isCancelled()) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                    if (result.equals("email already exist!")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Entered email already exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else if (result.equals("Error")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Insert Record Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
                                            String userEmail = response.getString("email");
                                            if (userEmail != null && !userEmail.isEmpty()) {
                                                for (int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
                                                    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                                                }
                                                String userID = response.getString("id");
                                                String fbID = response.getString("fb_id");
                                                String googleID = response.getString("google_id");
                                                String firstName = response.getString("first_name");
                                                String lastName = response.getString("last_name");
                                                String userPass = response.getString("password");
                                                String userMobile = response.getString("mobile");
                                                String userLocation = response.getString("location");
                                                String userDOB = response.getString("dob");
                                                String userGender = response.getString("gender");
                                                String posts = response.getString("posts");
                                                String following = response.getString("following");
                                                String followers = response.getString("followers");
                                                String userImagePath = response.getString("image_path");
                                                sessionManager.createLoginSession(userID, userEmail, fbID, googleID,
                                                        firstName, lastName, userPass, userMobile, userLocation,
                                                        userDOB, userGender, userImagePath, posts, following, followers);
                                                //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framePreLogin, new EnterPhoneFragment()).commit();
                                                saveSetting(userID);
                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                                        "Profile creation failed. Try again!",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }

                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            if (!dialog.isCancelled()) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Connection Timeout!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Auth failure error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Server error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "network error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Parsing error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("first_name", firstName);
                            params.put("last_name", lastName);
                            params.put("email", email);
                            params.put("password", password);
                            String firebaseRegistrationId = sessionManager.getFirebaseToken();
                            params.put("firebase_registration_id", firebaseRegistrationId);
                            return params;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                            return params;
                        }
                    };
                    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                    queue.add(stringRequest);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Network not available. Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: whats your exact problem ,is there data not fetching

Comment: app run with wifi exactly right but with mobile data connection server not give data with web services.

Comment: check with log-cat whether any exception or error occurred

Comment: com.android.volley.TimeoutError that's error is coming. but i was increased time with setRetryPolicy() even then response is not coming  with mobile data.

Comment: then its a network problem

Comment: data connection run my all other apps which installed in my mobile.

Comment: is your `Config.url` reachable from your mobile network?

Comment: yeah. with wifi is working fine.

Comment: i installed packet captured from play store in my mobile phone. when packet captured is running in background. Mobile data give response exactly right when packet captured is off. then mobile data not give response. Even that All things are same to send request on server with packet captured and without packet captured. my server is hostgator.

Comment: I ask if it is reachable `from your mobile network`, not from wifi

Comment: it is reachable from wifi but not reacable with mobile network as explain above A to Z.

Answer (score 0):

The sent data length is restricted in some devices when using mobile data, so try to make your data as less as possible.

Comment: you can define your answer in any example? but now i am using retrofit my problem is solved now.